PHP Solution to Leetcode "Group Anagrams" without Set Data Structure
I looked into the LeetCode problem 49. Group Anagrams:

Given an array of strings strs, group the anagrams* together. You can return the answer in any order.
* An anagram is a word or phrase formed by rearranging the letters of a different word or phrase, using all the original letters exactly once.

Here's my solution in PHP, but it doesn't pass all tests. For instance, it fails for the input ["ddddddddddg","dgggggggggg"]. Also, it becomes too slow when the input array is large.
Most examples I found are in Python and so much shorter using Sets.
What can I do to make this PHP solution work and more efficiently so?
class Solution {
/**
 * @param String[] $strs
 * @return String[][]
 */
function groupAnagrams($strs) {
    $result = [];
    $alreadyPlaced = [];
    $currentAnagrams = [];
    $hashed = [];

    foreach($strs as $key => $str) {
        // create assoc array mapping letter to index of str its from
        if ( array_key_exists($key, $alreadyPlaced) ) continue;

        // mark this as placed
        $alreadyPlaced[$key] = true;

        // initiatilize new array and place into new array
        $currentAnagrams = array();
        array_push($currentAnagrams, $str);

        // to be able to determine anagrams, hash each letter in the newly found string
        $hashed = array();
        foreach (str_split($str) as $c) {
            $hashed[$c] = true;
        }

        //loop thru all strings skipping those of not same length or already accounted for
        foreach($strs as $checkKey => $checkVal) {
            $breakout = false;
            if (mb_strlen($checkVal) != mb_strlen($str)) continue;
            if (array_key_exists($checkKey, $alreadyPlaced)) continue;
            foreach (str_split($checkVal) as $c) {
                
                if (!$hashed[$c]) {
                    $breakout = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if ($breakout) continue;
            // if it got here, its an anagram
            array_push($currentAnagrams, $checkVal);
            $alreadyPlaced[$checkKey] = true;
        }
        //add new palindrome array into $result array
        array_push($result, $currentAnagrams);
    }
    return $result;        
}


Your code does not solve the problem: it doesn't account for duplicate letters.
For instance, take this input:
["aaabb","aaaab","abbbb","aabbb","ababa"]

It is expected to return an array with four subarrays, but your code puts all strings in the same subarray.
It is not enough to set a boolean for each unique letter in a string and use that as a hash. That doesn't account for how many times a letter occurs, and will give false positives.
Algorithm
You could use array_count_values to count the occurrences of each letter and produce an associative array with letters as keys and counts as values.
Then sort this associative array by its keys -- which takes constant time, since there are at most 26 entries in it.
Finally encode this associative array as JSON (or use any other serialisation function, like serialize), which uniquely defines the group a string belongs to, and can be used as key in the result array.
Implementation
    function groupAnagrams($strs) {
        $groups = [];
        foreach ($strs as $str) {
            $count = array_count_values(str_split($str));
            ksort($count); // As there are at most 26 entries, this is O(1)
            $groups[json_encode($count)][] = $str; // Serialize the key
        }
        return $groups;
    }


Chose this amongst the others because asides being succinct, reminds why the sort is ok being O(n).
Honestly don't know when I will get good at Leetcode!!!

Thanks! Just want to note that the sort step is O(1), not O(), and this is only the case when the target has been reduced to the 26 entries. If the sort is applied to the input directly (after making it an array), it is at least having a worst case complexity of O() -- when using a bucket/radix/counting sort algorithm -- and it could even be O(log) when using a standard comparison sort algorithm.

Sorry, actually meant O(1)

You have way too much code here. You start well, but overcomplicate the process of grouping the anagrams. Here's my solution:
<?php

/**
 * Solution.php
 *
 */
class Solution {
  public function groupAnagrams(array $strs) {
      $output = [];
      foreach($strs as $anagram) {
          $strArray = str_split($anagram);
          sort($strArray);
        $output[join($strArray)][] = $anagram;
      }
        return array_values($output);
  }
}

This simplifies the process by sorting the characters in each source string. Each anagram of a given word will generate the same sorted list, which makes it easy to compare anagrams.
Use that sorted anagram as an index into an associative array, and add the original word to an array at that index. If the anagram hasn't been seen a new entry is created. If it has, the word is added to the output array.
Finally, return only the values from the associative array to meet the requirements of the challenge.
The solution is accepted for both run time and memory.


Your algorithm running time is O(N x N x M).
We can optimize it further, and avoid using sort() since the sort() itself is O(N Log N), which makes the total running time O(N x N x Log N):

class Solution
{
    function groupAnagrams($strs)
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($strs as $word) {
            $hash = $this->genHash($word);
            $res[$hash][] = $word;
        }
        return $res;
    }

    function genHash($word)
    {
        $count = array_fill(0, 26, 0);
        $alpha = ord('a');
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
            $count[ord($word[$i]) - $alpha]++;
        }
        return implode(',', $count);
    }
}

function run()
{
    $solution = new Solution();
    print_r($solution->groupAnagrams(["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]));
}

run();



Results:
Array
(
    [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] => Array
        (
            [0] => eat
            [1] => tea
            [2] => ate
        )

    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] => Array
        (
            [0] => tan
            [1] => nat
        )

    [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bat
        )

)


Time Complexity: O(N x M)
Space Complexity: O(N x M)

